# can't call uuid function after install npm uuid in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, uuid

i can't call the uuid function after installing npm uuid in JS, using electron

here is the message on the terminal when i install it, i don't know if this properly installed or not

```
$ npm install uuid
npm WARN pemrograman_visual2@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN pemrograman_visual2@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ uuid@7.0.3
updated 1 package and audited 120 packages in 1.746s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

and this is where i call the function

```
ipcMain.on("appointment:create", (event, appointment) => {
    appointment["id"] = uuid();
    appointment["done"] = 0;
    allAppointment.push(appointment);

    CreateWindow.close();

    console.log(allAppointment);
});
```

but when i run the program using $npm start it says TypeError: uuid is not a function

Comment: Did you import it like `const uuid = require('uuid').v4;`?

Comment: yes i import it like this `const uuid = require("uuid");`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) that's how you import uuid:

#### Using import/export syntax:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
uuid();
```

#### Using commonJs syntax:

```
const uuid = require('uuid').v4;
uuid();
```