# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function uuid in reactjs and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, uuid

I'm using reactjs with webpack 4 and got this message:
[TypeError: Object(...) is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VKOy.png)

App.js:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
console.log(uuidv4());
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.jsx'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.png|jpe?g|gif|ttf|woff|woff2|eot|svg$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    ..........
};
```

Comment: try import { v4: uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier not working

Comment: This library seems to be highly recommended library at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid, the correct usage according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61009998/7470360 and in the official docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid). Yet, I'm getting the same issue

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?